# SSIS script Component error

Tags: ssis

Get substring of a string in ssis script component throw error:

> Index and length must refer to a
>   location within the string. Parameter
>   name: length
>
> at
>   System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32
>   startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean
>   fAlwaysCopy)    at
>   ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer
>   Row)    at
>   UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer
>   Buffer)    at
>   UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32
>   InputID, PipelineBuffer Buffer)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32
>   inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)

Code:

```
 public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.ORGANISATIONPROVIDERSOURCEIDOut = Row.ORGANISATIONPROVIDERSOURCEID.Substring(0,19);
    Row.ORGANISATIONPROVIDERIDOut = Row.ORGANISATIONPROVIDERID;
}
```

any help please.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means your ORGANISATIONPROVIDERSOURCEID  string is less than 19 characters.  The SubString function's second parameter (length) cannot be greater than the length of the text.